# Type (function signature) is not assignable to type 'never' when exporting

Tags: typescript

I have the following function which I'm exporting, a pretty basic one:

```
export async function doThing(thingId: string) {
  await fetch(
    new URL('http://server/doThing/'+thingId),
    {
      method: 'POST',
    }
  )
}
```

upon typecheck it gives the error:

`Type '(thingId: string) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

which goes away if I'm not trying to `export` the function. Trying to figure out where exactly the implicit typing to `never` occurs?

(this is part of a nextjs project if that matters)

Comment: Where does the error occur???

Comment: this is part of a nextjs project, when I'm running my `next build` command

Comment: Uh huh. But the error should tell you where the error occurs... What file, line, column, etc

Comment: I can't reproduce this in any environment I have easily available.  Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue or enough information for others to reproduce.